# Create the [opensemanticsearch] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

Can someone create tag for the [opensemanticsearch](https://opensemanticsearch.org/) solution if it is reasonable?

Proposed description is:

> Open Semantic Search engine. Questions about installation issues, usage, tools integration. Should be used for questions directly about Open Semantic Search or in combination with other tags to specify context of the question. For example: [solr][opensemanticsearch]

It builds on top of well known search tools and solutions, but there are still some very specific questions related to Open Semantic Search and its usage.

For example, I posted the following question, but I'm not sure which are the best tags for it: [Clean index for opensemanticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66888635/clean-index-for-opensemanticsearch)

Comment: the tag excerpt better describes when the tag needs to be used on a question. It doesn't need to be an advert for the concept. Askers already know what it is, otherwise they wouldn't add the tag.

Comment: @rene, thanks, Proposed description was edited, based on your feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've created the tag for now. Be aware that I have the feeling a lot of questions on that topic might be related to configuring, installing or using that product.

I would prefer a wiki is suggested by you (you can do that yourself anytime [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/opensemanticsearch/info)) that explains the strict programing scope required for the questions in that tag. I don't want to have to burninate or clean-up a tag I created in 6 to 8 weeks.

Please keep eye on new questions in that tag so it is used properly.